# XmlnsDefinition does not appear to work

Tags: .net, xaml, xml-namespaces

I have a solution containing two projects: a WPF application called "MyTest.TestApplication" and a class library called "MyTest.ClassLibrary", with corresponding default namespaces. MyTest.TestApplication has a reference to MyTest.ClassLibrary. MyTest.ClassLibrary contains a class called MyTest.ClassLibrary.TestClass. I want to add an instance of this class to the application's resources, but using a URL as the Xml namespace value.

So, I open MyTest.ClassLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs, add a

```
using System.Windows.Markup
```

directive, and then at the very end I add the line

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.test.com/test", "MyTest.ClassLibrary")]
```

I build the project, go to MyTest.TestApplication.App.Xaml, and I add a namespace definition to the Application element. As soon as I type xmlns:t=", I get an intellisense list of assembly names and uris, but not http://schemas.test.com/test. If I add the namespace definition anyway, like so:

```
xmlns:t="http://schemas.test.com/test"
```

and add the following to the Resources element:

```
<t:TestClass x:Key="myTest" />
```

then that resource does not get created, and the Xaml editor complains that the class TestClass does not exist in the namespace http://schemas.test.com/test.

Frustratingly, I added a default WPF Custom Control library called WpfCustomControlLibrary1, added the line

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("bluh", "WpfCustomControlLibrary1")]
```

to WpfCustomControlLibrary1.AssemblyInfo.cs, built the project, referenced it in MyTest.TestApplication, and as soon as I began typing xmlns:b=" in App.xam, intellisense brings up the list of namespaces with "bluh" at the very top.

I tried adding all sorts of assemblies and using directives to MyTest.ClassLibrary, but I can't get Visual Studio to find my assembly via the schema URL. Amazingly, it does work if I set the namespace to the assembly name, like so:

```
xmlns:t="clr-namespace:MyTest.ClassLibrary;assembly=MyTest.ClassLibrary"
```

So.. what's going on here?

**EDIT:** Frustratingly, I finally got it to work after two hours of searching by simply removing the reference from the WPF application, and then re-adding it. Ugh. I guess this is some sort of VS2012 bug?

Comment: Hah! Same. The project reference removed itself. Re-adding worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem with "ClassLibrary" as assembly name. Just spent some time now because Resharper returned

```
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'BMN.Utils.Logging.ConfigLogger' 
from assembly 'ClassLibrary, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Changing the assembly name to BMN.Utils.Logging.UnitTests solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Since "bluh" works, try:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition(@"http://schemas.test.com/test", "MyTest.ClassLibrary")]
```

maybe the slashes are throwing the compiler off.

Comment: Not working either. I even used just "test" instead of "http://schemas.test.com/test", but no dice.